# Problem on direction of frictional force on pulley staying on a pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Think there is a block on a pulley with friction .  Now you are giving a force resisting the downward motion (provided that the block should be kept on equilibrium) of the block ( due to gravity) . Now you are addressed that the magnitude of the force is F . And mass of the block is M . These two aren't definite numbers. Now considering that you have to apply the same amount of force needed to keep the box in equilibrium.  Now in which direction should the friction work? In the direction of F or in the downwards of the pulley. My attempt: I think as the gravity is the mandatory force the friction should oppose gravity.

Comment: You are referring to *static friction*. Static friction is not fixed in magnitude nor in direction. Suppose you have a block resting on rough table with maximum possible static friction is $10 N$. Suppose you push the block with force of $2 N$ to the right. The block will not move and static force is $2 N$ to the left. Now suppose $F= Mg$ in your problem.This is equivalent to the block in rest with no external forces. Now slowly increase the force and consider how the friction changes in magnitude and direction.

Comment: @npojo the type of situation I'm talking about  is that I'm also trying to push your block with 10N. So it doesn't move. But while solving a problem where I need to write the force equation. I would have to think about the direction of the friction. Now this is still static friction. I guess.

Comment: Actually, you have to think **physics** not **equations**. Try to solve the block-on-table question: What force should be applied to keep the block at rest. You will find a *range* of solutions with each solution characterized by different static friction (magnitude and direction).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulley - on which side is tension bigger? Two different answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now in which direction should the friction work? In the direction of F or in the downwards of the pulley. My attempt: I think as the gravity is the mandatory force the friction should oppose gravity.

The situation is that the Block  has a tendency to  move downward and as long as  this tendency  persists the frictional  force which is taken as static friction will act opposite to gravitational force.

If one has reached equilibrium i.e.

**F + Mg =0**  where F is acting upward; that is no external force is acting the frictional force should be zero as the block has no tendency to move up or down.

However to reach the above sharp condition one will slowly raise the variable Force **F** to reach above condition and all through this region **( F < Mg)** of application of **F** the block will be intending to move down and therefore the friction will act opposite to **Mg**.

IF  however **F** has been raised such that it exceeds the value of **Mg** and  the  Block intends to move up the frictional force  will act downward.